# afiledialog android library not working | NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, filechooser

I am trying to get to work this android library
https://code.google.com/p/afiledialog/
it also has a sample project named aFileDialogTesting but I cannot get it to work.
I'm getting error NoClassDefFoundError when I run it.
I'm also getting "Could not find class 'ar.com.daidalos.afiledialog.FileChooserActivity', referenced from method ar.com.daidalos.afiledialog.test.AFileDialogTestingActivity$13.onClick"

Probably there is wrong in referencing the android library project.
But how can I reference it correctly?

Comment: have you define FileChooserActivity in AndroidManifest.xml or have you added this library in build path?

Comment: I have added this library in the build path. there is no need to define FileChooserActivity in AndroidManifest.xml. Have you got it to work?

Comment: can you please try to add this <activity android:name="ar.com.daidalos.afiledialog.FileChooserActivity" /> line in your project AndroidManifext.xml ? or just read "How to use it" from given link.

Comment: The sample project, aFileDialogTesting which I am trying to get to work already has this in the AndroidManifest.xml. btw, I added the android library using java Buildpath > projects > add > aFileDialog > ok

Comment: Right click on aFileDialogSamples -> Properties -> Android - > add aFileDialog to Library section.

Comment: thanks. it work! please answer this question so that I can vote for you. :)

Comment: Please check i add as ans thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
Right click on aFileDialogSamples project -> Properties -> Android - > add aFileDialog Library project to Library section in right side.
```